# Ansible Compare two list / dictionary keys items in both directions bi-directional / symmetric for delta or difference without creating a new variable

Tags: ansible

**# ansible --version**

ansible 2.9.27

**ansible-playbook --version**

ansible-playbook 2.9.27

Ansible has a built-in difference filter: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/difference_filter.html

i.e.

```
# It will return the elements of list1 (which are not in list2) if you use difference()

# Example:

list1: [1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 4, 10]
list2: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 99]

# Running the following will Will give you (i.e. the items of left list, not in right list)
{{ list1 | difference(list2) }}
=> [10]
```

This difference filter **does NOT compare delta between two lists** here **in both directions**, in both directions. I wish they had some extra parameter to this function to set 0/1 for checking it in both directions).

Currently it's comparing entry of list1 and showing the delta(items) of list1 which are NOT in list2, otherwise, it'll return a BLANK list [] (i.e. **length == 0**).

For bi-directional check, I have to find delta of list2 comparing with list1 too, but that will require creating another **var** variable. i.e. `new_var: "list2 | difference(list1)"` but **I'd prefer NOT to** create another variable (if possible) as I don't have any need to do any actions  which are based on just *list1* or just *list2* specific delta/difference.

**In my Ansible playbook (or a role's XYZ/tasks) .yml file, I have a task with conditional `when` statement (as listed below):**
First I find list JSON blob by hitting REST API end point of **Exports** object (in OneFS PowerScale Isilion) and then, I set a fact by reading exports object from that JSON output.

```
- name: Get exports status
  uri:
    url: "{{ onefs_isilon_endpoint }}/platform/4/protocols/nfs/exports?zone={{ access_zone }}"
    user: "ansible"
    password: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['ansible_secret'] }}"
    method: GET
    force_basic_auth: yes
    return_content: yes
    status_code: 200,404
    body_format: json
    headers:
       content-type: "application/json"
    validate_certs: no
  register: isi_exports

- name: Identify Current Exports
  set_fact:
    cur_exports: "{{ isi_exports.json.exports }}"

- name: Do something
  command: echo 'hello world'
  vars:
    export_clients: "{{ cur_exports | json_query(query_clients) | join('') }}"
    
    export_clients_delta: "{{ client_ip.split(',') | difference(export_clients) }}"
  when: export_clients_delta | length > 0 or export_root_clients_delta | length > 0
```

If you notice, the last variable `export_clients_delta` is the only one used in `WHEN` conditional check, to allow the task to run or skip it.

I'm passing a variable at cmd line (or through a file while running the playbook) **let's say** it's: `client_ip: 10.30.40.50,10.40.50.60` **and** from **OneFS Isilon Exports** (using REST Api *GET* operation) the json object has an export's client IPs list coming as: `export_clients: 10.20.30.40,10.30.40.50,10.40.50.60` then,

**My goal is:** to run the conditional task (as listed above).

**Which is currently not happening** as the task is getting ***SKIPPED*** (as both IPs of `client_ip` variable (aka list1) exists in the second list == the one on the right side aka `export_clients` (passed inside difference filter).

In this `WHEN` conditional, we used `length` to find if list is greater than 0, I'm thinking, if we can do something like to set the delta variable, then it'll work *i.e. finding delta difference in both sides and adding the list, if lenght is > 0 then I want it to run*, **and I don't need to maintain/create another variable** to find delta for list2 (comparing with list1)

```
(list1 | difference(list2)) + (list2 | difference(list1))
```

thus, is the following possible?

```
export_clients_delta: "{{ client_ip.split(',') | difference(export_clients) + export_clients.split(',') | difference(client_ip) }}"
```

but that gave me an error.

```
fatal: [isilon]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'export_clients_delta | length > 0 or export_root_clients_delta | length > 0' failed. 

The error was: error while evaluating conditional (export_clients_delta | length > 0 or export_root_clients_delta | length > 0):

{{ client_ip.split(',') | difference(export_clients) + export_clients.split(',') | difference(client_ip) }}: 'list object' has no attribute 'split'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/isilon/roles/myrole/tasks/main.yml': line 28, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Do something\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Comment: Your error is, IMO telling you what the problem is quite clearly: `export_clients` is already a list, and so, it does not have a `split` method > `... + export_clients | difference ...`. Also if you are using `client_ip.split(',')` in the first part, you should also use it in the second part > `... | difference(client_ip.split(','))`

Comment: This said, mind that `vars` at the task level are only visible to that task, like a local variable, so there is no real reason to not want to define as much variables as needed for clarity, as long as they are the task level.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I agree, that was the case. Not sure why difference filter didn't have this simple format of `difference(list1,list2,0)` for directional check (left sided) and `difference(list1,list2,1)` where 3rd parameter will compare both lists i.e. bi-directional check. Would be great if they can update difference filter to get this part done. Less coding.

Comment: That filter does exists actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter you are looking for is the [`symmetric_difference`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/symmetric_difference_filter.html) one.

Here is a demonstration of it it being the same as your attempt:

```yaml
- block:
    - debug:
        var: list1 | difference(list2) + list2 | difference(list1)

    - debug:
        var: list1 | symmetric_difference(list2)

  vars:
    list1: [1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 4, 10]
    list2: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 99]
```

Which yields:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  list1 | difference(list2) + list2 | difference(list1):
  - 10
  - 11
  - 99

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  list1 | symmetric_difference(list2):
  - 10
  - 11
  - 99
```

---

You can find an exhaustive list of the filters that are part of the *[set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory)* in the documentation page *[Using filters to manipulate data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory)*.

Comment: Awesome!! thanks for sharing. Now what we have in source of truth (will always be reflected in the target environment)

Answer (score 1):

Given the variables

```yaml
client_ip: 10.30.40.50,10.40.50.60
export_clients: 10.20.30.40,10.30.40.50,10.40.50.60
```

Q: ***"Is the following possible?"***

```yaml
delta: "{{ client_ip.split(',')|difference(export_clients) +
           export_clients.split(',')|difference(client_ip) }}"
```

A: Yes. It is possible. You have to split the lists first

```yaml
  list1: "{{ client_ip.split(',') }}"
  list2: "{{ export_clients.split(',') }}"
  delta: "{{ list1|difference(list2) + list2|difference(list1) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  delta:
  - 10.20.30.40
```

You can use the filter [*symmetric_difference*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/symmetric_difference_filter.html#ansible-builtin-symmetric-difference-filter-different-items-from-two-lists). The simplified expression below gives the same result

```yaml
  delta: "{{ list1|symmetric_difference(list2) }}"
```

You don't need the intermediate variables if you use this function. The expression below also gives the same result

```yaml
  delta: "{{ client_ip.split(',')|
             symmetric_difference(export_clients.split(',')) }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    client_ip: 10.30.40.50,10.40.50.60
    export_clients: 10.20.30.40,10.30.40.50,10.40.50.60
    delta: "{{ client_ip.split(',')|
               symmetric_difference(export_clients.split(',')) }}"

    list1: "{{ client_ip.split(',') }}"
    list2: "{{ export_clients.split(',') }}"
    delta1: "{{ list1|difference(list2) + list2|difference(list1) }}"
    delta2: "{{ list1|symmetric_difference(list2) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: delta
    - debug:
        var: delta1
    - debug:
        var: delta2
```

Comment: Yep, Vladimir. `symetric_difference` is what I was looking for in my case.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to compare for both sides was simply using** `+` (to concatenate 2 lists) and **for my error** using split on the correct object type (as shown below).

```
export_clients_delta: "{{ (client_ip.split(',') | difference(export_clients)) + (export_clients | difference(client_ip.split(','))) }}"
```

**NOTICE**: '(' and ')' around the statements of `+` operator to wrap both operations to ensure **if** the **order of items** is important while comparing, then it'll have a valid delta/diff entries shown.